# Can I use OpenVAS to keep up with Cisco security advisories?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I'm assuming this question is more security-centric so I'm posting it here instead of server fault.

I'm new to automated vulnerability scanning and I'm trying to wrap my head around what OpenVAS does and if it can solve my problem. I’ve downloaded the virtual appliance from the OpenVAS website and played with it, but now I think I have more questions than answers.

I'm primarily interested in OpenVAS to help me with one thing- keeping up with Cisco security advisories.

This is the Cisco security advisories feed: http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/publicationListing.x. It lists new vulnerabilities as they are discovered.

It is published in OVAL and CVRF.

I need a tool that can collect the OVAL or CVRF definitions and check if any of those vulnerabilities apply to my approximately 100 routers.

OVAL support in OpenVAS is still limited (http://www.openvas.org/integrated-tools.html says it’s using an old version of the open source library) and I have read nothing about CVRF support.

Comment: Have you tried to import the OVAL into OpenVAS? If that works you are probably OK. You can also contact the OpenVAS support list.